# Waypoints scrolling library & Webpack - Uncaught TypeError: n(...) is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, jquery-waypoints

I'm having some issues using the Waypoints library (http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) and Webpack.

When trying to require the Waypoints library and run the example code that I literally copy and pasted from their website (I changed the element ID), I receive this error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n(...) is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:formatted:610)
at n (bundle.js:formatted:11)
at bundle.js:formatted:71
at bundle.js:formatted:72
```

My js file is very basic right now and is as follows:

```
// var SlideInOnScroll = require('./modules/SlideInOnScroll');
const Waypoint = require('../node_modules/waypoints/lib/noframework.waypoints.js');

var waypoint =  new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('about-text'),
  handler: function() {
    alert('Basic waypoint triggered');
  }
});


console.log("hi from app js, after var waypoint");
```

My Webpack config file is also very basic and is as follows:

```
    var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./scripts/app.js",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./temp"),
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
}
```

When I pump my js file through webpack, I receive the error I mentioned above.  When diving into the bundled webpack file, the error in question shows the following:

```
    new (n(0))({
        element: document.getElementById("about-text"),
        handler: function() {
            alert("Basic waypoint triggered")
        }
    });
    console.log("hi from app js, after var waypoint")
}
```

HOWEVER!  When I forego webpack by adding a script tag in my html pointing to the Waypoints library, and use a script tag in my html to point to my JS file, it works perfectly fine.  No issues at all and I receive the alert when I scroll to the element.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Might help to add your webpack config file so someone can replicate your code. Or even better, create a GIT repo reproducing the error.

Comment: The [`noframework.waypoints.js`](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/lib/noframework.waypoints.js) file doesn't export or return anything so you can't assign the return value from `require` to `Waypoint`. It does add `Waypoint` to `window` though

Comment: @Phil I see, do you have a small code example of a work around, or how I can reference the window object to make the waypoints scroll function work?

Comment: err, `window.Waypoint`

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your help!  All I did was remove the 'var Waypoint = ' and kept the require statement, and things are working just fine and as expected.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Cool. There's a bunch of issues / feature requests on their issue tracker regarding this. For example https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/issues/523